# How to load an image in Java using toolkit and new URL

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I need to use a JPEG image in my Java applet.
In my applet class, I define the image name and create an object to ImageBuffer class.

```
String iname= "image1.jpg";
b = new ImageBuffer(iname,this);
```

In the ImageBuffer class, I call

```
Image image = null;
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(new URL(applet.getCodeBase(),fileName));
```

While this does not flag an error and image is not null anymore, it does not initialize `image` correctly. The `height` and `width` are -1. The url of the path however appears to be correct :  `/C:/Users/..../image1.jpg`

How do I correctly load the image? It is in the bin file of my Eclipse project currently.

Comment: `URL` of the path does not begin with a slash `/`  --> `/C:/Users/..../image1.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

> The height and width are `-1`.

Use a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) to monitor the asynchronous loading progress of the image.  Alternately use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to load the image prior to the next code line.

Answer (score 0):

If the `image` is placed in the correct location, then this would fix it

```
image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(new URL(applet.getCodeBase(),fileName))).getImage();
```

If the code returns a `NullPointerException` it means the `image` is not placed in the correct directory.